# How can i create a MDL lite card like this one with a divider in between

Tags: css, material-design-lite

im not good with mdl lite but i want to create an mdl card that looks exactly as it is on the image below how do i do that?

[image: mdl card example]

after reading on documentation this is what i came up with. but it doesn't look good.

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.header {
  color: #666;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  background: black
}

.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp demo-card-wide">

      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Account</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card__supporting-text">
          <h4> $600</h4>
          <p>Remaing Amount</p>
        </div>

        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card__supporting-text">
          <h4> $600</h4>
          <p>Remaing Amount</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlN6Y.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlN6Y.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `mdl-grid` within `mdl-card` makes sense, but won't give you much flexibility (e.g. the position of the separator/divider). I propose a solution with flex instead.

For the right aligned menu button I have used the `mdl-card__menu` from the [**card component**](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section). The rest, I leave it to you ;) Bare in mind the example you give does not use the default Roboto font.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body {
  padding: 0px;
}

.header {
  color: #666;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}

.demo-card-wide>.mdl-card__title {
  color: #fff;
/*   height: 50px; */
  background: black
}

.demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
  width: 350px;
}


/* Additional css below */

.mdl-card {
  min-height: 0;
}

.mdl-card__menu {
  color: white;
}

/* .mdl-card__title {
  padding: 12px 32px;
  align-items: center;
} */

/* .mdl-card__title-text {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
} */


.card-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-cell {
  text-align: center;
}

.card-cell h4 {
  margin: 8px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.card-divider {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp demo-card-wide">

    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Account</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mdl-card__menu">
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text card-content">
      <div class="card-cell">
        <h4> $600</h4>
        <p>Remaing Amount</p>
      </div>
      <span class="card-divider"></span>
      <div class="card-cell">
        <h4> $600</h4>
        <p>Remaing Amount</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dude thanks alot. how can i become good at css and other css libraries. gimme a word of advice please. thanks again

Comment: The best three resources that helped me learn CSS: 1) Video based learning sites like Codeschool and Pluralsight, they are both great, 2) You have to learn Flexbox asap after you learn the basics and 3) When you google search for a CSS term always add the word 'MDN' to the search (to get to the MDN site which I believe is the best resource at the moment in the internet around HTML/CSS/JS, thanks Mozilla!!!)